# What is an object in state machine diagram?

Tags: class, object, state, uml, state-machine

I'm trying to draw state machine diagram for my android app. Many web sites and books said that it shows transitions between various objects. Because of lack of UML knowledge, however, I can't understand the exact meaning of an object.

In https://www.uml-diagrams.org/object.html,
Object is an instance of a class.

So does an object mean instance of the specific class in the code or an entire system? I'm confused about this. Can you give me an example about an obejct?

Comment: I think you must have misread. It's transitions between **states** (of an object)

Comment: @GeertBellekens Yes, but I don't know which object's status means. Is it the status of the entire system or is it the status of an instance of a particular class? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The statuses of an instance of the class for which you are modelling the state machine. You can of-course consider your whole system as a class as well, and model the states for an instance of your system.

Comment: What does the first sentence say? _Object is an instance of a class._ What can be said more? And further: where did you read "transition between objects"?

Comment: @GeertBellekens I think I need to study more about UML. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @qwerty_so I read this at https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/uml-state-machine-diagram.  I think I need to study more about UML. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Guk Glad to read that :-) I know that there are many things that can be confusing around UML. But definitely it's woth the effort. If you got any issues there are quite a number of answers here. And if there's no fit then you can always start a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Objects in UML

An object is defined in UML as follows:

> A classifier describes a set of objects. An **object** is an individual with a state and relationships to other objects. The state of an object identifies the values for that object of properties of the classifier of the object.

But this is difficult to grasp: the definition of a classifier relies on the concept of object, and the definition of object relies on the concept of classifiers. The shorter "objects are instances of classes" do not help to sort this chicken and egg problem out.

To make it even harder, this way of seing objects fits well [class based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming), but less the [prototype-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

### Objects more pragmatically

I will not try to explain what has already been explained in hundreds of books.  Let's take Grady Booch's definition (he is one of the UML founder):

> **Object:** Something you can do things to. An object has state, behavior, and identity; the structure and behavior of similar objects are defined in their common class. The terms instance and object are interchangeable.

Even better, [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)'s very naive but nonetheless very helpful definition :

> An **object** packages both data and procedure that operates on that data.

### States

"State" is an ambiguous term, and may not refer to the same reality when used in "object state", and "state of a state machine".

For objects, the state often refers to all the data of an object.  If you save and restore all the data of an object, you would expect that it its operations will lead to the same results and the same behaviors.  This is often true, but not always.  A more accurate definition from Booch is:

> The cumulative results of the behavior of an object; one of the possible conditions in which an object may exist (...)

A state of a state machine has a slightly different meaning.  A state correspond not to a single object state but to a set of possible object states (of a single object, or of several objets, or of a whole system).  Usually a state-machine state describes in very broad terms the underlying set. A state could for example describe a stage in the lifecycle or operations (created, initialized, in use, archived, discarded) of an object or a component.

Example for a state machine controlling a room's temperature:

```
Named state (State machine)   Object state
TOO_COLD                      temp=12, min=16, max=19, power=1500
                              temp=13, min=16, max=19, power=1500
                              temp=15, min=16, max=19, power=900
RIGHT_TEMPERATURE             temp=16, min=16, max=19, power=100
                              temp=18, min=16, max=19, power=50                   
                              temp=19, min=16, max=19, power=50   
TOO_WARM                      temp=20, min=16, max=19, power=50
                              temp=21, min=16, max=19, power=0
                              temp=20, min=16, max=19, power=0
```

In this example, you can see that the state machine state can (and mostly will) correspond to a (potentially large) set of object states.

Comment: I think the GoF definition rather describes a class. The main differnce between object and class is that objects are "real world things" while classes are what their name says: a classification of real world things. `Tree` is a class while the apple tree in front of my house is an object.

Comment: Further for state machines I think that since the object has a state it is represented by a state machine. This itself may consist of several sub-state machines. But all in all there is nothing really to distinguish.

Comment: @qwerty_so Wouldn’t the gof definition also works for languages such as js where each object could potentially define its own class through prototyping mechanism?

Comment: @qwerty_so about the state of object vs. system, I agree with you that the system can be composed of a multitude of submachines (we all live in a yellow submachine… ah! no! it was submarine). But even if you break down a state such as “waiting” at the smallest possible object, it corresponds not to a single object-state but to a range of possible object states. Isn’t there a subtle difference here between the singularity of a specific object state and the multiplicity of possible states implied by a single machine state?

Comment: Yes and no. Of course the state of a sub-state machine is not the state of the object. But the difference should (my POV) only be made between sub-/state machiness which all together represent the object state. I would not see a semantic difference between an object state and a state machine's state.

Comment: There is no point in defining classes for their own purpose. You use classes to classify, hence the word. Most famous is the work of Carl von Linné.